# Submitting login fields during a scraping process with ruby?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize, typhoeus

I need to scrape some financial data from a system called NetTeller.

An example can be found [**here**](https://www.sfonline.org/controller.aspx?p=/e-n-services/netteller-online-banking).

Note the initial ID field prompt:

[image: ID field]

Then once you submit you have to then enter your password:
[image: Password field]

As you can see, it has a two step process where you first enter an ID number and then after submission the user is presented with a password field.  I'm hitting some roadbumps here when it comes to jumping through these two hoops prior to getting on into the system and getting to the data that I actually want.  How would one process a scenario such as this where you need to pass through the authentication fields prior first before getting to the data you want to scrape?

I have assumed that I could just jump in with `httpclient` and `nokogiri`, but am curious if there are any tricks when dealing with a two-page login such as this before getting into your target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize).  The first page is "tricky" because the login form is within an iframe. So you could use just the source where the iframe is being loaded. Here is how:

```
agent = Mechanize.new

# Get first page
iframe_url = 'https://www.banksafe.com/sfonline/'
page = agent.get(iframe_url)
login_form = page.forms.first
username_field = login_form.field_with(:name => "12345678")

# Get second page
response = login_form.submit
second_login_form = response.forms.first
password_field = second_login_form.field_with(:password => "xxxxx")

# Get page to scrap
response = second_login_form.submit
```

This is how you could process an scenario like this. Obviously you might need to adapt to exactly how those forms/fields are written and other specific-page details, but I would go for this approach.